# Erlang hello world problem?

Tags: erlang

I can't understand why this doesn't work:

```
    -module(hello).
    -export([hello_world/0]).

    hello_world() -> io:fwrite("hello, world\n").

(hello_world@PC)8> hello:hello_world().
** exception error: undefined function hello:hello_world/0
(hello_world@PC)9>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you compiled your source code? Type `c(hello).` in Eshell (assuming that `hello.erl` is the name of the source file) before calling the function.

Comment: Im using the eclipse plugin for erlang. i'm following these steps and they didnt mention compiling:
http://erlide.sourceforge.net/erlide.html#running_project

Comment: ErlIDE for Eclipse should normally compile your code every time you save it.

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix that:

Go to: 
Run configurations
--Erlang
Select tab:
--Environment
then
--Select
check
-- Path
Apply and run.

Now you'll be good to go.